# MODULE_NOT_FOUND error - Not able to run the node js application with sqlite3 in the docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux, node-sqlite3

I facing this below error while running my nodejs-16 application using docker. I started facing this issue after I update my node from v14 to v16. I googled but couldn't understand.

Can someone throw me light on what can be the fix for this?

```
Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v6-linux-glibc-x64/node_sqlite3.node'
Require stack:
- /usr/src/app/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3-binding.js
- /usr/src/app/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3.js
- /usr/src/app/build/entity/data-service/sqlite.helper.js
- /usr/src/app/build/entity/data-service/dataservice.controller.js
- /usr/src/app/build/route.js
- /usr/src/app/build/index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:833:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1057:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3-binding.js:4:17)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1209:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:868:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1057:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/usr/src/app/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3-binding.js',
    '/usr/src/app/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3.js',
    '/usr/src/app/build/entity/data-service/sqlite.helper.js',
    '/usr/src/app/build/entity/data-service/dataservice.controller.js',
    '/usr/src/app/build/route.js',
    '/usr/src/app/build/index.js'
```

Here is my docker file

```
FROM node:16-alpine AS builder
RUN mkdir -p /myloc/usr/src/app
WORKDIR /myloc/usr/src/app

COPY package.json ./
#build all the local images in the base node container
RUN npm install
COPY . .

RUN npm run build
#RUN npm run test

FROM node:16-slim
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY --from=builder /myloc/usr/src/app .

# Add user nodejsuser
RUN groupadd --gid 2000 nodejsuser \
  && useradd --uid 1300 --gid nodejsuser --shell /bin/bash --create-home nodejsuser
RUN chown -R nodejsuser:nodejsuser /usr/src/app

USER nodejsuser
EXPOSE 4000

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

The image is successfully built but when I run the container, I'm seeing this issue.

Comment: How are you actually running the container?  Is there an anonymous volume mounted over your `node_modules` directory?  The contents of that volume will take precedence over the contents of the image, and you might be using libraries built for the wrong Node version.

Comment: The mismatch in underlying Linux distributions between the two build stages is also a potential problem.  As you have this set up, you're not really gaining anything from the multi-stage build, and you might try deleting the four lines from the second `FROM` up to the `COPY --from=builder` line.